# Compute ERA5 daily climatology without consuming lot of memory

Tags: climatology, era

I am trying to compute daily climatology of ERA5 data, but without using **append** and **concat** so that I do not consume a lot of memory.

My idea was to read every file and update it by adding the next file and then dividing it by 2 in a loop. To do this, I tried to use the += operator. I am writing it in the code-snippet below. Since, I am reading inside the loop, I am not really updating it. Can anyone please tell me, how I can update **rain_clim** as I read along. Many thanks.

````
rain_clim=[]
for i in flood_years:
        rain_clim=xr.open_dataset('Rainfall-'+str(i)+'.nc')
        rain_clim+=rain_clim
        rain_clim=rain_clim/2```
````

Comment: Don't divide by 2 each time! Simple add all of them, create a counter that add 1 per time and then divide by that counter at the end

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But my main problem is, **rain_clim+=rain_clim** is not updating **rain_clim**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to use dask?

Comment: @gerrit: thanks. I have not tried dask. I am trying to learn how to use it. Meanwhile, if you do not mind, it would be great if you can give me a quick pointer using my snippet as example.

Comment: @BidyutBikashGoswami I don't have a snippet, but you can google documentation for xarray and dask in combination.  I think you can also open all datasets together, without a loop, using zarr or xarray mfdataset.  Sorry, no time for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

On line 3, `rain_clim=xr.open_dataset('Rainfall-'+str(i)+'.nc')`, every time the loop iterates, `rain_clim` gets set to the value of the current data set. Follow user arkaia's suggestion, along the lines of either `rain_clim += xr.open_dataset('My_File')` or

`rain_clim = []` 
`for i in range(n_flood_years):` 
    `tmp = xr.open_dataset(files[i])` 
    `rain_clim += tmp` 
`rain_clim = rain_clim / (i+1)  # sensitive to 0-based or 1-based indexing`

Apologies for the poor formatting

Comment: There is also the ncra command to make netcdf record averages

Comment: Hi John, I tried your way but it gives "ERROR: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (12,2) ". FYI, my input files have dimension=>
time: 12 longitude: 360 latitude: 180; and the n_flood_years is an `array([1977, 1988, 1990])`

Comment: Thanks. I know about ncra or cdo. I just need to do it in Python.

Comment: `n_flood_years` should be an integer and it should be 3. Need to confirm that rain_clim and tmp have the same dimension - I am not very familiar with xarray, so I'm sure there are some syntax details I am overlooking.